# Store all the things that got printed to windows CMD in a file

Tags: java, windows, cmd

Is there any way I can save all the things that is happening on my Windows 7 Command Prompt in a  file. So that I can see what are the things that got printed on the console. I am running a multithreaded Java Program from the command prompt as-

```
java -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Duser.timezone=GMT-7 –jar BatchMain.jar -taskId V3-PERSONALIZATIONGEO-SAMPLE-TASK -noofthreads 1 -timeout 5 -numberOfIP 1000 -privateIPAddress false
```

And it prints lot of things on to the command prompt, And I want to store all these things that are getting printed on the console into a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either capture the output directly in your program, or on the console.

### On the console

If you want to get absolutely everything (both STDOUT and STDERR), you need to redirect STDOUT (from System.out) and STDERR (from System.err). You can either redirect both to the same file (add `> log.txt 2>&1` to the end of your console command), or you can log them to different files (add `> BatchMain.log 2> BatchMain.err` to the end of your console).

Log to a single file, log.txt:

```
java -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Duser.timezone=GMT-7 –jar BatchMain.jar -taskId V3-PERSONALIZATIONGEO-SAMPLE-TASK -noofthreads 1 -timeout 5 -numberOfIP 1000 -privateIPAddress false > log.txt 2>&1
```

Log to separate files, BatchMain.log and BatchMain.err:

```
java -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Duser.timezone=GMT-7 –jar BatchMain.jar -taskId V3-PERSONALIZATIONGEO-SAMPLE-TASK -noofthreads 1 -timeout 5 -numberOfIP 1000 -privateIPAddress false > BatchMain.log 2> BatchMain.err
```

### Directly within your program

In your `main(String[] args)` method (or some other appropriate place), set System.out and System.err to print directly to files (or the same file, if you wish). For example:

```
package com.example.logging;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class LogToFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream("example.log"));
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("example.err"), true));

        System.out.println("System.out example");
        System.err.println("System.err example");
    }

}
```

If you want the output to also be visible on the console, you can go a step further and insert your own intermediate PrintStream which does this.

### Other things to consider

Note that Java buffers System.out, so if you log both STDOUT and STDERR to the same file, you could end up with nonsensical output that has the two PrintStreams interwoven, or something in STDOUT could be printed much later than a related message that was printed to STDERR. One workaround is to call `System.out.flush()` as appropriate, but this could degrade performance if you're logging a lot of text to `System.out`.

Rather than printing everything to the console with `System.out.println()` and trying to capture that output, I'd recommend using [Java Logging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/util/logging/overview.html) or [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/), or going a step further and using [Apache Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/), which can be configured to use either of the first two systems internally. The really awesome part is that you don't have to divine which class printed each log message, because you'll get that automatically.

If you use a logging framework, you can also adjust the verbosity of your logging output by setting a single variable--which will come in handy at release time.

Answer (score 1):

You can write " > outfile.name" after command

Comment: Updated the question, I am running a multithreaded java program from the command prompt so it prints lot of things to windows CMD prompt so I need to store all these things that are getting printed into a file.

Comment: Does "java -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Duser.timezone=GMT-7 –jar BatchMain.jar -taskId V3-PERSONALIZATIONGEO-SAMPLE-TASK -noofthreads 1 -timeout 5 -numberOfIP 1000 -privateIPAddress false > outfile.txt" work?

Comment: @dwrd the method you talked about does work. I made a quick answer giving another way to go about handling this, and a few things about your method. The way you talked about isn't the absolute best way if you need to monitor the command prompt screen constantly. It also records every single piece of data (whether it was needed to be logged or not) to the file you specify.

Answer (score 1):

As far as Java programming goes, you'd have to make some sort of logging system in order to write all of the program's output to a file, or more than one file if you're looking for organization. If you only need certain pieces and parts of the data, I recommend using this method.

[Dwrd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10115263/1311659) is correct. However, this would not be the code you're looking for if you only need certain parts of the output (such as an IP Address) From start to end of the program, all output will be written to the file that you specified. To be more clear on the subject at hand, you would use this code:

```
java -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Duser.timezone=GMT-7 –jar BatchMain.jar -taskId V3-PERSONALIZATIONGEO-SAMPLE-TASK -noofthreads 1 -timeout 5 -numberOfIP 1000 -privateIPAddress false > myLog.txt
```

The downside of this is that there will be no output given to the command prompt screen.

Comment: And where this file will be there, It will create myLog.txt file automatically at that location from where I am firing the command prompt.

Comment: That is correct. You're able to specify a path if you'd like, but if you do not and only provide the file name, it will be created in the same directory as the prompt.

Comment: I don`t understand problem now. You can of cource specify path after ">" sign.

Comment: @Anthony, in more particular case (in sence of situation when there is no logger), you can also set custom output stream to std output in every point of program. It can help in such situations like debugging. You can even create own stream that writes to some set of specified streams. Of course logger better than this aproach, but I think that in the question situation it isn`t implemented.